# Evaluating the integral $\int \frac{1}{x+ \text{ ln }(x)}dx$

Tags: integration

Can someone evaluate the following integral: $$\int \frac{1}{x+ \text{ ln }(x)}dx$$

Any help or reference to a solution would be appreciated.

Comment: It is likely that this cannot be expressed in terms of elementary functions.

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integral%5B1%2F%28x%2Blog%28x%29%29%2C+x%5D

Comment: You may be right, thanks anyway!

Comment: Are you sure it's not $\dfrac1{x\cdot\ln x}$ by any chance ? If not, see [Liouville's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville's_theorem_(differential_algebra)) and the [Risch algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risch_algorithm).

Comment: The basis behind this question was to get an analytic solution to the ode: $$ \frac{dx}{dt} = x + \text{ ln }x $$ which needs the solution of the above integral.

Comment: Please note that even the stationary solution of this ODE have to expressed in Lambert W-Functions, so i would guess that the general solution will be not expressible in terms of known functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In terms of a power series the integral can be seen as the following.
\begin{align}
I &= \int \frac{dx}{x + \ln(x)} \\
&= \int \frac{1}{1 + \frac{\ln(x)}{x}} \, \frac{dx}{x} \\
&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \, \int \frac{ (\ln(x))^{n} }{ x^{n+1} } \, dx \\
&= \ln(x) + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^{n+1}} \, \Gamma(n+1, n \, \ln(x)),
\end{align}
where $\Gamma(a,x)$ is the incomplete gamma function.